# Limit of a sequence $\frac1{n + 1} + \frac1{n + 2} + \cdots + \frac1{n + n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Do you know how to calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac1{n + 1} + \dfrac1{n + 2} + \cdots + \dfrac1{n + n}\right)\,?$$

Would be it correct to present this as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n\dfrac1{n + k}\right)\,?$$

Comment: There must be a typo in your first expression.  Should the numerator of the second term be $1$, or should the numerator of the last term be $n$?

Comment: Did you mean $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac1{n + 1} + \dfrac1{n + 2} + \cdots + \dfrac1{n + n}\right)\,?$$

Comment: @AndrewChin that was a typo in my edit. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: @an4s: Your edit has a typo "2" in some numerators.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would be it correct to present this as  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n\dfrac1{n + k}\right)\,?$$

Yes.

> Do you know how to calculate

One way it to see that it is an integral.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n\dfrac1{n + k}\right) 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1n\sum_{k = 1}^n\dfrac1{1 + k/n}\right) \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac1{1+x}dx\\
&= \ln(1+x)\Big|_{x=0}^{x=1} = \ln2 - \ln1\\
&= \ln2 \approx 0.693
\end{align}$$
The integral is the limiting process of dividing interval $[0,1]$ in $n$ parts of width $1/n$ and considering the area under the function $f(x) =1/(1+x)$. That area is split into $n$ rectangles of heights $f(x)$ and same widths $1/n$. As $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$, $k/n$ finally ranges from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: but where this 1/n dissapears ?

Comment: or we can consider that 1/n like a infinitely small (dx in integral ) ?

Comment: @paweta : The $1/n$ does not disappear. In Riemann integral with equi-distant division of the area, the area under the function is divided in $n$ rectangles of height $f(x)$ and same width $1/n$. Loosely speaking, the $1/n$ becomes the $dx$ in the integral.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The formula
$$H_n=\ln n + \gamma + O\left(\frac1n\right)$$
is derived Apostol's Analytic number theory [page 55](http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA55).

You are looking at the limit of $H_{2n} - H_n$, can you finish this yourself?

Comment: Well, currently I'm studying calculus II, and I haven't seen this formula yet. Would it be easier way to solve it ?

Comment: @paweta see the answers in the duplicate question, converting to an integral.